# Is there a way to use cloud messaging without displaying a notification in Flutter using Firebase or other cloud messaging platforms?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

i am developing a mobile application using Flutter. I was wondering if we can use Cloud Messaging for data transfer or event listening purposes without giving user an actual app notification if app is currently running.

For example;

- User taps on "make payment" button and result of that payment process is produced from an async method in a microservice that we don't know when it will return the result thus we can not synchronously wait the result on mobile.

Can i use cloud messaging for these purposes without popping up a notification?

Thank you for your answers and time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are saying like listening some notification data something like this

```
// This is when app is running not on background   
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage? message) {
        RemoteNotification? notification = message!.notification;
        // just use message!.data it depends on you
        // notification!.data
        // is always return Map e.g. { "id":"sampleId"}
       // so call it like notification!.data["id"]
        if(notification!.data!= null){
              // Do your thing here.
         }
        
         });
```

Comment: So that way, i don't have to push a notification when a message comes from firebase, right? I can do whatever i want with that data without a notif.

Comment: Yes, Since on that part notification or message should goes there as long as you include data on the push notification body

Comment: there is another problem. I am using python "firebase_admin" package to send push notifications from my service to mobile devices. If there is no "notification" parameter on RemoteMessage object, iOS devices does not display a notification at all, not even when app is on background. If i add "notification" parameter to object, then on iOS devices, notification is displayed even the app is running. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: for viewing notification are you using flutter local notification?

Comment: I am not using that package, notification is displayed by itself, without me doing anything..

Comment: I solved it, it is about "setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions()" method. I set alert and badge params to false and no more notifications when app is running.

Comment: "setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions()" havent tried this but am glad you solve yours.